# ubuntu 18.04 server ufw is not blocking even after configuring DOCKER_OPTS="iptables=false"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, firewall, ufw

i have been trying all the solutions i found to block incoming traffic to port 5432 but with no success. there is an issue with docker skipping ufw and it has been advised to configure DOCKER_OPTS="iptables=false" in /etc/default/docker, i have done that too but still it's not working. can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to expose your Postgresql to the internet you can map to only localhost in `docker-compose.yml`

```
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:5432:5432'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because docker is overriding iptables,
here is the solution;
https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/11/03/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker.html

long story for short;
edit /etc/default/docker and uncomment the DOCKER_OPTS line:

```bash
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --iptables=false" 
service restart docker
```